# Cabal dependency conflict when installing yesod

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod

I am trying to install the [yesod](http://www.yesodweb.com/) web framework.

When I run `cabal install yesod-platform`, I get a dependency conflict:

> cabal: dependencies conflict: ghc-7.0.4 requires array ==0.3.0.2 however
>   array-0.3.0.2 was excluded because http-conduit-1.8.7 requires array >=0.4

I get this error even in a [hsenv](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/hsenv) sandboxed environment.

What can I do?

Comment: You can upgrade to a newer GHC, 7.0.4 is rather old now, or you can try installing an older yesod(-platform). I don't know how far back you'd have to go for one that builds with 7.0.4, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Daniel Fischer says, this is not a dependency conflict so much as a recognition that yesod doesn't support 7.0.4, and hence your dependencies are outdated. 7.0.4 is well before the current Haskell Platform, and you should upgrade.